# Why does my class refuse to bind to ListBox?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I don't know what's wrong with my code, it shows no errors but when I run the code no listbox appears in the emulator.The aim of the code was to show a thumbnail image next to a 
hyperlink element.I have already checked that all image locations are valid and that all images have been set as type content.

```
 public class element
    {
       public string imageLocation { get; set; }
       public string name {get; set; }
    }

    var source = List<element>();
    //I then populate source with 4 elements (code omitted)
    //The source list was created successfully

    listBoxName.itemsSource = source;
```

In Xaml

```
<ListBox Name ="listBoxName"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                            >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Canvas Name="List" 
                                 Tap="tapped_Click" 
                                 Background="Blue"   
                                 Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0">

                            <Image  Name="Thumbnail"    
                                    Source="{Binding imageLocation}"     
                                     Height="102" Width="126" />

                            <HyperlinkButton Name="link" 
                                             Content="{Binding name}" 
                                             Margin="0,0,0,84" Canvas.Left="128" 
                                             Canvas.Top="2" Height="96" Width="348" 
                                             FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        </Canvas>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your listbox is correctly binded, but it's not displayed because its width is equal to 0.

Either set the width of your canvas, or use another kind of container (like a grid):

```
<ListBox Name ="listBoxName"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Canvas Name="List" 
                    Tap="tapped_Click" 
                    Background="Blue"   
                    Height="100" Width="476" Margin="0,0,0,0">

                <Image  Name="Thumbnail"    
                        Source="{Binding imageLocation}"     
                        Height="102" Width="126" />

                <HyperlinkButton Name="link" 
                                Content="{Binding name}" 
                                Margin="0,0,0,84" Canvas.Left="128" 
                                Canvas.Top="2" Height="96" Width="348" 
                                FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```